# Apple suggests don't create umbrella framework then what is the workaround when my sdk needs to use other dependencies?

Tags: swift, sdk, frameworks, xcframework

I have created one XCframework which needs to use other pod dependencies like Alamofire.

Apple suggests not using an umbrella framework then what is the workaround when we have a situation like this?